# How to include Shiny element inside dropdown area in reactable

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I want to include a slider input inside a dropdown area of a reactable.

This is my code:

```
library(reactable)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)

df <- data.frame(areas = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                 col = c('Trick', 'Trick', 'Trick', 'Trick'),
                 W = c(5.04, 4.57, 3.5, 3333.2),
                 Z = c(1113.415, 1.3,1.23, 1.09),
                 E = c(1122245.27, 11300, 34999.98, 803))

table_left <- reactable(
  df,
  style = list(fontFamily = "Roboto, sans-serif", fontSize = "0.875rem"),
  striped = TRUE,
  details = function(index) {
    sales <- df$df[index]
    tbl <- reactable(df, outlined = TRUE, highlight = TRUE, fullWidth = FALSE)
    htmltools::div(style = list(display = ''),
                   div(class = "date_slider",
                       sliderInput(inputId =  "proj_slide",
                                   label = "SHINE DATE RANGER SLIDE",
                                   width = '50%',
                                   
                                   min = as_date("2006-01-01"), 
                                   max = as_date("2021-06-01"),
                                   
                                   value = c(as_date("2006-01-01"),
                                             as_date("2021-06-01")
                                   ))),
                   
                   div(class = "first_model_inf",
                       
                       h3("Model Info"),tbl)
                   
    )
  },
  onClick = "expand",
  rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer")
)
```

But `sliderinput` doesnt shows up.

Even when I am on shiny app environment.

Any help?

Comment: `details` is expecting a Javascript function, not an R function. Any R expression would not work